# How to restart camera preview on Xamarin forms when using a custom renderer view for a camera preview

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to resume my Camera preview with android after putting the app to sleep or changing between apps. Or even starting a different app which uses the camera feature but the Camera crashed with getParameters() being null. 
Is there a way to retrieve the control other the camera preview when resuming using the Xamarin forms application.

I have tried to use Camera.Restart() and didn't work.

```
        public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Preview != null)
                {
                    Preview.StopPreview();
                    Preview.Reconnect();
                    Preview.SetPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    Preview.EnableShutterSound(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"           ERROR: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            Preview.StopPreview();
            Preview.Release();
        }

        public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, Android.Graphics.Format format, int width, int height)
        {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = Preview.GetParameters();
            parameters.FocusMode = Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousPicture;
            IList<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.SupportedPreviewSizes;
            // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
            Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes[0];
            parameters.SetPreviewSize(previewSize.Width, previewSize.Height);
            Preview.SetParameters(parameters);
            Preview.StartPreview();
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire demo in github, I will try your project at my side.

Comment: This is only the native part 
https://pastebin.com/G4Tuy0Qp

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by reading more thoroughly about the behaviour of the Android camera(Camera1) hardware.
If you are working on Xamarin and trying to create camera view within the app the best way to do it is making a custom renderer and create a camera view in each platform. Like shown here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

but this example only shows how to create the camera preview, there is no camera hardware lifecycle or taking a pictures included.

To solve the issue for the question above I had simply to do Camera.Open(0) to gain control over the camera again within the lifecycle of Xamarin forms pages.

Here is what I did(in CameraPreview class in Xamarin Forms):

Created Camera open event handler:

```
public event EventHandler CloseCameraRequest;
```

Created a method to invoke the event:

```
public void OpenCamera()
    {
        OpenCameraRequest?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Registered the handler in the android camera native class:

```
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CameraPreview> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            _nativeCameraPreview = new NativeCameraPreview(Context);
            _nativeCameraPreview.PhotoCaptured += OnPhotoCaptured;
            SetNativeControl(_nativeCameraPreview);
        }
        Control.Preview = Camera.Open(0);
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            e.NewElement.OpenCameraRequest -= OnOpenCameraRequest;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            e.NewElement.OpenCameraRequest += OnOpenCameraRequest;
        }
    }

    private void OnOpenCameraRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control.Preview = Camera.Open(0);
    }
```

Invoked the request all the way from Xamarin forms page OnAppearing method:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        CameraPreview.OpenCamera();
    }
```

This fixed the issue of resuming camera preview after opening other application which uses the camera or putting the app to sleep where camera preview will timeout.